# Returning the textbox value of another form after initializing it?

Tags: c#, input

I'm trying to make my own custom input dialogue by designing a form. How would I initialize it so that once I press OK, I can receive the value of the textbox in it, back to where I initially called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form that exposes a property like this:

```
public class InputDialog:Form
{
    public string Result { get; set; }

    private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Result = txtResult.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And in your base form you do:

```
var dialog = new InputDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
string Result = dialog.Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `events` for communication between forms. This way `InputForm` hides logic, properties from outside world.

```
public class InputEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Input { get; private set; }

    public InputEventArgs(string input)
    {
        Input = input;
    }
}

public class InputDialog : Form
{
    public EventHandler<InputEventArgs> InputSet;

    private void OkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ev = InputSet;

        if (ev != null)
        {
            ev(this, new InputEventArgs(txtInput.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

and in your calling form:

```
private void ShowInputForm()
{
    using (var frm = new InputDialog())
    {
       frm.InputSet += (s, e) =>
       {
          txtResult.Text = e.Input;
       }

       frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```